# find network location from URL elegantly

Tags: python, regex, urlparse

code:

```
import urlparse
url1 = 'http://try.github.io//levels/1/challenges/1'
netloc1 = urlparse.urlparse(url1)[1]  #try.github.io

url2 = 'https://github.com/explore'
netloc2 = urlparse.urlparse(url2)[1]  #github.com
```

`netloc2` is I want,however,I hope `netloc1` is `github.io`,if  use regex,how to handle it.

Comment: You've got a working Pythonic solution and want to write a regex to do the same - is that correct?

Comment: The problem is that you need a list of TLDs to get this to work. For example, what would be the netloc in `foo.bar.com.br`? Opposed to `foo.bar.com`. There is no way to get this working for all TLDs without having a list of valid TLDs.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for from the question. Would you be able to expand the "given 'this' I'm expecting 'that'" portion?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regex will validate the url's contain either `try.github.io` or `gethub.com`

`^https?:[\/]{2}(try[.]github[.]io|github[.]com)`

[image]

## Example

I don't know python so I'm providing a php example to show how the regex works.

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/^https?:[\/]{2}(try[.]github[.]io|github[.]com)/im',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://try.github.io
            [1] => https://github.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => try.github.io
            [1] => github.com
        )

)
```

## Disclaimer

It would probably be easier to use your `urlparse` solution and then just apply some logic to test the `[1]` returned value.